# Plan for Mulder in "Herrenvolk"

Tags: the-x-files

At the end of "Herrenvolk" (Season 4), as the Alien Bounty Hunter

> restores Mulder's mother at the behest of the Cigarette Smoking Man,

the Smoking Man explains to the Bounty Hunter in regards to Mulder that the fiercest enemy is the one with nothing to lose.

When the Bounty Hunter asks why he cannot simply dispose of Mulder, the Smoking Man insists that Mulder is an integral part of their plans — meaning the plans upon which the alliance between his Syndicate and the

> alien colonists who once inhabited the Earth

is based.  This leads to a natural question:

**Which integral part of their plans was the Smoking man referring to, exactly?**

Mulder, of course, is deeply opposed to the secret activities of the Syndicate.  Much later, at the end of Season 6 and the start of Season 7 in the episodes "Biogenesis", "The Sixth Extinction", and "The Sixth Extinction Part II: Amor Fati", we find out that

> Mulder has become a type of alien-human hybrid, one that required no surgical intervention or extended experimentation.  His genetic code had been altered by a prior exposure to a form of *Purity* (most likely in Tunguska in the episode of the same name), and the result means that he is now the second truly successful hybrid, after Cassandra Spender.  The creation of a slave race as part of the plans for colonization require successful hybrids,

and so Mulder might fit into the plans in that way.

However, it is not clear that this outcome could have been anticipated, as

> Mulder's capture and exposure in Tunguska was not part of a pre-conceived plan, and the Smoking Man seems as surprised as anyone about Mulder's neurological condition and transformation in "The Sixth Extinction Part II".

So then, what is Mulder's importance to the plans for colonization?

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield:   If you believe it is policy that " character tags area bad idea"  then you might want to look at this http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81218/why-didnt-fawkes-rescue-dumbledore-in-the-half-blood-prince

Comment: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/1566/2816

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield: and this http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81945/why-did-peter-quill-wait-26-years-to-open-his-mothers-gift

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield:   Hey, I don't care.   I just noticed a bunch of X-Files questions popped to the top of the list at the same time and went to go see why.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield: and this http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68056/who-was-more-powerful-sauron-or-morgoth   ---   are you sure you want to pursue this?    Maybe it would be better to alias these to 'specific-character' or something -- otherwise you will be continually cleaning them up.   That's not a good solution either.

Comment: comments isn't really the place to go over this but "continually cleaning up" these sites is part of what high-rep users and mods do. *shrug*

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield : My instinct is to reinsert the character tags, on the basis that *other sci-fi realms in scifi.se have character tags*.  Before turning my attention to X-Files questions, I was very active in Star Trek questions, where we have the tags captain-kirk, jean-luc-picard, star-trek-data, spock, and so on.  These are frequently used without objection.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield : My concern is consistency.  Are we going to remove the character tags from Star Trek posts?  (I'll hold off on inserting any X-Files tags until we have consensus.  Also, I'm happy to move this discussion over to meta.)

Comment: yeah, let's not do this here; can you please read the meta link I put up there, and Giles' answer; then, if you still think they should go back, take it to meta and we'll get consensus.