# What did the letter from Peter Quill's mother say?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1

At the end of Guardians of the Galaxy, Peter Quill opens a [26-year old gift](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/81945/79413) containing a cassette labeled "Awesome Mix Vol. 2" and a handwritten note from his mother.

What was written on the letter from Peter Quill's mother?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Peter,
>
> I know these last few months have been hard for you, and I know it's
>   because of the special bond that we share. But I'm going to a better
>   place and I will be okay, and I will always be with you. You are the
>   light of my life, my precious son, my little Star-Lord.
>
> Love,
>   Mom

**Note**: The written letter differs slightly from what we hear in the film. The on-screen letter includes the line "*and I know it's because of the special bond that we share*".

[image: Written letter from Peter's mom]

However, this line is omitted when we hear Peter's mom read the letter aloud.

([Thanks to Edmund for pointing out this difference](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/163038/what-did-the-letter-from-peter-quills-mother-say/163039#comment471223_163039))

Comment: Unfortunately, your answer is not correct. As suggested by meh, and extended by the community, the written letter differs (slightly, but still) from what is read in the movie. And the question was about what was **written**  in the letter.

Comment: @EdmundDantes How does the letter differ?

Comment: It misses the part "and I know it's because of the special bond that we share."

Comment: @EdmundDantes Thank you for the correction. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The above mentioned post, missed what everyone else missed, even the movie does not have it as a voice line. This is what was written on the letter (differs from what was spoken)

Peter,

I know the last few months

have been hard for you, and

and I know it's because of the

special bond that we share.

But I'm going to a better place

and I will be okay and I

will always be with you.

You are the light of my life.

my precious son,

My little Star-Lord

Love,

Mom

Source:  At 0:22

Comment: Can you provide a source for these words? Maybe an image of the letter you're reading off?