# Why didn't Albus Dumbledore lift the Anti-Apparition wards like he did in the Great Hall?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, albus-dumbledore, apparition

If Dumbledore can lift the Anti-Apparition wards even temporarily, like in the Great Hall, why didn't he do it in the Astronomy Tower? Wouldn't that have allowed him to do more in the Battle of Astronomy of Tower? If he couldn't Apparate because he was weak, Harry could have Apparated him as he had done from the Crystal Cave to Hogsmeade.

> As you may know, it is usually impossible to Apparate or Disapparate within Hogwarts. The headmaster has lifted this enchantment, purely within the Great Hall, for one hour, so as to enable you to practice. May I emphasize that you will not be able to Apparate outside the walls of this Hall, and that you would be unwise to try.

Comment: Dunno, but maybe it takes more than a moment to remove the wards.

Comment: The only "evidence" I can find is [this link](http://wandw.wikidot.com/spell:anti-apparition-charm) to an rpg-version of the charm (which, since it's for an unofficial game variation of the source material, I'd take it with a grain of salt), suggesting it takes time to cast. Other than that, any further clarification would have to come from Rowling herself.

Comment: I think there is fair evidence within the quote used 'you will not be able to Apparate outside the walls of this Hall'. The change allowed for apparition between two points within Hogwarts, not to the outside.

Comment: Not sure why this would be opinion based.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince: Why didn't Dumbledore Apparate?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8767) - specifically *"Dumbledore chose not to Disapparate from the Astronomy Tower the night he was killed. He and Snape had a plan worked out that Dumbledore was determined to follow through with"*

Answer (score 1):

There is an indication within the quote you have used:

> May I emphasize that you will not be able to Apparate outside the walls of this Hall, and that you would be unwise to try.

Apparition was allowed within a small area of Hogwarts, not between the school and any external location. It does not show that removing the protection entirely would be possible, or if it was achievable that it would be quicker than apparating to Hogsmeade and walking/flying back to the school.

Comment: I don’t think the quote is really relevant here. In that instance there was no reason to remove the protection from any area besides the Great Hall, so they didn’t. It doesn’t indicate that the protection can’t be removed from other areas. Indeed, it would be strange if the protection could only be removed from one specific area.